# otool output for iOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, dylib, otool

If I run `otool -L ...` on the main executable of my iOS .ipa file, I see the following output:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
  /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
  ...
  @rpath/DMSDK.framework/DMSDK
  ...
  /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
  /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
  /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`

This tells me the dynamic libraries that are used/referenced/required by my app.

My question: do these refer to global directories that exist *on the ios device itself*? I believe the answer's yes, but wouldn't that imply that all iOS devices already have `libsqlite` installed on them (I'd only find this surprising because as a web dev I thought sqlite was more of a userspace thing and I'd be surprised it'd have enough support from Apple to be a pre-installed dylib)?

How come some dylibs originate from `/System/Library/Frameworks` and some from `/usr/lib/...`? I can find a [list of iOS frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html), but where can I find the list of supported `dylib`s built into iOS devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those do refer to libraries on the iOS device, because they must be available when the app launches on the device. The `@rpath` entry refers to something bundled with the app, but anything beginning with `/` is included with iOS. All iOS devices have SQLite installed, because it's used by various Apple frameworks (Core Data, and also internally by others). For what it's worth SQLite is also a standard part of macOS, for the same reason.

In most cases the `/System` paths refer to frameworks provided by Apple, which include a dynamic library as well as resources (images, sounds) used by the framework. [When developer tools are on a Mac, frameworks also include header files.] The `/usr/lib/` paths are anything else, including third-party open source libraries like SQLite as well as anything with a more Unix-style dynamic library.

Outside of an iOS device itself the only way I know to find a list of included libraries is to install Xcode on a Mac and browse `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib` (there are similar paths for Apple Watch and Apple TV). For what it's worth, [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/atomicbird/ccacf1e25bff4b2e88dbb77a21d4dacb) of what I get with Xcode 8.3.2.

Comment: I'm sure this is answered elsewhere but looking through the rest of the iPhoneOS.platform directory I only see headers and .tbd files; is it correct to say/think that `.tbd` files are only there to describe which dylibs / symbols _will_ be present on the target device (without having to actually provide real dylibs in that directory that need to be inspected with otool/nm/etc?)

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. The `tbd` files are text files, and you can look at the contents to see the symbols that will be available on the iOS device.